# Kdevelop doesn't show the editor window

Tags: editor, kdevelop

I'm trying to open a project file in the main editor of kdevelop, but it is not able to show it. I have tried also with a new file, but still the same. It seems that there is a window separator in the middle of the grey window.

I have remove the project, purge and reinstall the application but it doesn't work. The Editor menu in the tools bar doesn't have nothing inside.

I'm using kubunu 11.10, KDE 4.7.3 and KDevelop 4.2.3

Does anybody had this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your projects tool view is not enabled. If yes, Go to Window, select Add Tool View. Then select Projects. Then try opening up your project file (something.kde4). It should show up as a folder in the Projects Pane. Expand it and double click your required source file to get it in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with KDE 4.7.4 and kDevelop 4.2.3.

I think, its a bug of kdevelop. after closing all projects and importing the working project again I tried to open a file. But kDevelop was crashed. After restarting kdevelop, everything is working fine and the file is shown in the editor!